# Rounded png image border glow effect

Tags: html, css, png, border

Please take a look at this fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/SkjHs/4/

```
<html>
<ul class="langBar">
  <li><a href="?lang=az&amp;page=main"> <img src="http://goo.gl/aIxpv"> </a></li>
  <li><a href="?lang=en&amp;page=main"> <img src="http://goo.gl/wIQob"> </a></li>
  <li><a href="?lang=ru&amp;page=main"> <img class="activeLang" src="http://goo.gl/If4lA"> </a></li>
</ul>
</html>
```

```
html {
background-color:#000;}
.langBar{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
}

.langBar li{
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 40px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.activeLang{
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    border-radius: 20px;
    border: 2px solid #482663;
}

.langBar li a{
    display: block;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}
```

I'm trying to achieve some nice glow effect around `activeLang` class image. First problem is, i'm getting padding between border and image itself. Second can't get glow effect. Any suggestions?

Comment: There is no padding around the images – but there is a transparent area within the images. You have to rework those images to get rid of the unused, transparent areas.

Comment: @feeela We can use inset shadow thing

Comment: If you use `inset` shadows, the outer line won't fade to the background but is a sharp border, while the inner part of the circle fade out (but is hidden behind the image).

Comment: Ideally, you should ask one question per ... question.

Comment: Is there any reason you're not spriting the language-images into one sprite? In that case, it'd also be an easy feat to make a second column or set of sprites for "on-state" with the glow just as you want it. It would also cut down on two extra http requests (insignificant by themselves, but if they're added into the rest of your site, well, it all adds up), and you wouldn't have to play guessing games to get the radius /just-so/.

Comment: BTW: flags belong to countries, whereas languages are spoken across multiple countries; so using flags for a language select is not the best option available. (Though there are some flags tha are in fact in use for a language, e.g. Arabic, where the [flag of Arabic Revolt](http://commons.wikimedia.org/wiki/File:Arabic-Language-Flag.svg) is used.)

Comment: @mori57 I can't do it, can you do it for me please?

Comment: See my jsFiddle (answered below) for an example of how you could do it. http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/n3Q74/

Answer (score 2):

First of all the padding of the image is because of image canvas [**My Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/SkjHs/9/)

Image with canvas cropped

[image]

Add the below CSS to `.activeLang` for glow like effect to your image...(Ofcourse you can change colors as per your choice)

```
box-shadow: 0 0 3px 3px #888;
```

And Remove from `.activeLang`

```
 width: 32px;
 height: 32px;
```

Comment: Yes, to get your attention. I can remove it after the edit. See: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/84342/answer-that-only-contains-a-link-to-jsfiddle and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/149890/prevent-posts-with-links-to-jsfiddle-and-no-code

Answer (score 1):

Such a glow effect could be realized via a `box-shadow`:

```
/* pink glow effect */
box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #f3a;
```

See http://jsfiddle.net/SkjHs/8/ for an example with glow effect.

Or (as I would set it up) a solution without using `img`-tags:

```
<ul class="langBar">
    <li><a href="?lang=az&amp;page=main" class="icon icon-az">[AZ]</a></li>
    <li><a href="?lang=en&amp;page=main" class="icon icon-en">[EN]</a></li>
    <li><a href="?lang=ru&amp;page=main" class="icon icon-ru active">[RU]</a></li>
</ul>


.langBar {
    overflow: hidden;
}

.langBar li{
    display: block;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.icon {
    display: inline-block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    margin: 5px 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    text-indent: 110%;
    -webkit-border-radius: 20px;
    -moz-border-radius: 20px;
    border-radius: 20px;

}

.icon:focus, .icon:active, .icon:hover,
.icon.active {
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #f3a;
    -moz-box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #f3a;
    box-shadow: 0 0 5px 5px #f3a;
}

/* one may use a sprite and only set the background position here */
.icon-az {
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/aIxpv);
}
.icon-en {
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/wIQob);
}
.icon-ru {
    background-image: url(http://goo.gl/If4lA);
}
```

http://jsfiddle.net/SkjHs/10/

Answer (score 0):

Even when using border-radius, a border won't go inside the element.  The few pixels at the edge of each image file force the border outside of the content of your image.

[image]

I recommend editing your image to remove the spacing, or even to add all of the effects you want on rollover.

Answer (score 0):

As an example of spriting making shorter work of the issue:

```
<ul class="langBar">
    <li><a id="az" href="?lang=az&amp;page=main"></a></li>
    <li><a id="en" href="?lang=en&amp;page=main"></a></li>
    <li><a id="ru" href="?lang=ru&amp;page=main" class="activeLang"></a></li>
</ul>

html {
background-color:#000;}
.langBar{
    display: block;
    overflow: hidden;
    float: left;
    width: 125px;
}

.langBar li {
    display: block;
    width: 32px;
    height: 32px;
    float: left;
    margin-left: 7px;
    padding: 0px;
}

.langBar li a {
    background: url(https://lh5.googleusercontent.com/orZ4dkDz2lBVJMB7D0Pb2fBHB8JPLcD8r2xqSYw-e3K7K2G427Ws_iqNbcYF1U2X36ju1y3eVy0) no-repeat 0 0;
    display:block;
    width:32px;
    height:32px;
}

.langBar li a#az {
    background-position:0 0;
}

.langBar li a#en {
    background-position:0 -32px;
}

.langBar li a#ru {
    background-position:0 -64px;
}

.langBar li a.activeLang, 
.langBar li a#az.activeLang, 
.langBar li a#en.activeLang, 
.langBar li a#ru.activeLang {
    background-position-x: -46px;
}
```

​
Thought this was a little lengthy, which is why I put this in a jsFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/mori57/n3Q74/

Hope this helps!

Comment: Same technique can be expanded on to do mouseovers using the :hover spec, as well, but this at least gets the effect you were talking about without having to try guessing with the border-radius (and dealing with its incompatibilities across older versions of IE).